# Clarification on proofs of mathematical induction?

Tags: linear-algebra, induction

could someone explain something to me about this proof I saw:

"Prove $n^2$ is less than $2^n$ for all integers $n>5$
....
STEP 2:
Suppose $k>5$ is an integer for which the statement is true.
That is, suppose $k^2>2^k$

Prove $(k+1)^2<2^{k+1}$, best done by proving RHS - LHS$>$$0$

RHS-LHS=$2*2^k - (k+1)^2$

$>2k^2-(k^2+2k+1)$, by the induction hypothesis

$=k^2-2k-1$

$=(k-1)^2-2$

$>0$, since $k>5$ and so $(k-1)^2>16$"

The only part I don't understand is how we proved RHS-LHS>0. Did we basically just prove that RHS-LHS>$(k-1)^2-2>0$, and hence $(k+1)^2<2^{k+1}$?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is where your induction hypothesis comes into play. You already know that $2^k < k^2$, so you just plug that into your equation (first inequality) and therefore you can deduce that $2^{k+1} < (k+1)^2$ by showing RHS-LHS $> 0$.

Comment: How is this deduced though? Its probably something very simple, but I'm just not grasping it. 

We prove that RHS-LHS>0 by showing that RHS-LHS>(k-1)^2 -2 (by the induction hypothesis), then we prove that this result is greater than 0, hence showing that RHS-LHS>0, right?

Comment: Well you know that $(k-1)^2-2$ is strictly increasing (for $k>5$) and positive for $k=5$ (and even below that). Does that help you?

Comment: Alright, I understand now. Thanks

Comment: Feel free to mark it as answer if it helped you ;-)